# python sqlite3: How to use LIKE and ? to do partial matching?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

With python sqlite3, I'd like to something like

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM songs WHERE filename LIKE "?%"', (key_string,))
```

so that I can use the key as a variable instead of having to hard code the pattern.
But this does not work and gives me:

```
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the answer my self:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM songs WHERE filename LIKE ?', ('{}%'.format(key_string),))
```

Comment: what is the key_string? is it the matching string?

Comment: @east.charm a string to use as a keyword